# terraform templatefile Function Invalid template interpolation value(AKS Cluster Name)

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I try to provision an azure dashboard using terraform module and template file but I get an error message:

> Call to function "templatefile" failed:
> src/main/terraform/environment/modules/someservice/resources/dashboards/infrastructure-dashboard.tpl:41,39-55:
> Invalid template interpolation value; Cannot include the given value in a
> string template: string required., and 25 other diagnostic(s).

The error is being caused by the code in the template. It does not accept the variable declared in the dashboard properties. The code in the template causing the error:

```sh
"clusterName": "${k8s_cluster_name}",
```

Terraform code:

```sh
resource "azurerm_dashboard" "infra-dashboard" {
  name                = "${upper(terraform.workspace)}-Infrastructure"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgp-dashboards.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rgp-dashboards.location
  tags = {
    source = "terraform"
  }
  dashboard_properties = templatefile("${path.module}/resources/dashboards/infrastructure-dashboard.tpl",
    {
      md_content                  = var.infra_dashboard_md_content,
      dashboard_title             = var.infra_dashboard_title,
      dashboard_subtitle          = var.infra_dashboard_subtitle,
      sub_id                      = data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id,
      rgp_k8s                     = azurerm_resource_group.seervice-k8s.name,
      k8s_cluster_name            = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.service-k8s.*.name,
      rgp_service_env_global_name   = azurerm_resource_group.service-env-global.name,
      log_analyt_wrkspc              = local.log_analyt_wrkspc
  })
}
```

Snippet from the tmeplate where the error occurs:

```sh
"1": {
            "position": {
              "x": 0,
              "y": 4,
              "colSpan": 9,
              "rowSpan": 4
            },
            "metadata": {
              "inputs": [
                {
                  "name": "queryParams",
                  "value": {
                    "metricQueryId": "node-count",
                    "clusterName": "${k8s_cluster_name}",
                    "clusterResourceId": "/subscriptions/${sub_id}/resourceGroups/${rgp_k8s}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/${k8s_cluster_name}",
                    "workspaceResourceId": "/subscriptions/${sub_id}/resourcegroups/${rgp_service_env_global_name}/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/${log_analyt_wrkspc}",
                    "timeRange": {
                      "options": {},
                      "relative": {
                        "duration": 21600000
                      }
                    },
                    "cpuFilterSelection": "total",
                    "memoryFilterSelection": "total_memoryrss"
                  }
                }
```

Comment: `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.service-k8s.*.name` probably is not a string.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how can print in terraform console?

Comment: Yes, you have right. It is not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As luk2302 said azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.service-k8s.*.name it is not a string. In fact it is a tuple

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
join(",", azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.service-k8s.*.name)
```

will join all entries with an ",". Replace it with whatever you need

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that will not work for me. azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.service-k8s.*.name is a tuple and I don't need to join all the names.

Comment: How would you like the `k8s_cluster_name` variable to look like then? Should it contain all values from the tuple or just one specific name? You'll need to explain that :D